# Command to identify which all sources (gcp bucket etc.) are feeding into a pub/sub topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Please let me know whether there is any command to  identify which all sources (gcp bucket etc.) are feeding into a pub/sub topic.

Answer (score 1):

By design, you can't know it! Indeed, anyone with correct credentials can publish a message in a topic. It's not a registration pattern, and thus you don't have a list of authorized publisher!

However, there is some workarounds to narrow your search

- Firstly, look at the accounts authorized to publish into PubSub at the project/folder/org level, and the into this specific topic at PubSub topic level.
- Then, you can create a pull subscription and you can parse the messages, especially the attributes. Like this, you can know the source bucket (for example) that publish into this topic
- Finally, if you know that a bucket publish event into a topic(s), you can run this command to see all the notifications generated by the bucket.

```
gsutil notification list gs://MY_BUCKET
```